# How to avoid a relation-property to include its own relation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }


}
public class Organization
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following two tables created with EF code first.
I need to retrieve my User with Org but I don't want Org property to then again include the same User. How can I avoid that, so all I get is the user with the org?

This is the line that's causing me trouble:

```
        return await _context.Users.Include(x => x.Organization).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to retrieve my User with Org but I don't want Org property to then again include the same User.

Either remove the `Organization.User` navigation property or, if you just want to remove it from a serialized output, decorate the navigation property with [JsonIgnore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) (or similar)